# To prove that $\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, metric-spaces

I am practically clueless on how to prove the triangle inequality here. The case is evident when $|z|≤|x|$ and $|z|≤|y|$. But how do I prove it in general?

Any hint/answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know if this is indeed true, it should also follow that $\min_z(d(x,z)+d(y,z)) \ge d(x,y)$. This can be proved using $\frac{d}{dz}(d(x,z)+d(y,z))$, although it will be quite messy.

Comment: @MartinR this is evil

Comment: @acarturk The answers to the question are truely messy.